# Keeping a value by reference inside a closure

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

Given the following example I'd like to use `z` by reference inside my closures:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
  x: Box<dyn Fn() + Send + Sync + 'a>,
  y: Box<dyn Fn() + Send + Sync + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  fn new(z: &'a str) -> Foo<'a> {
    let x = Box::new(|| { z; });
    let y = Box::new(|| { z; });
    Foo {
      x,
      y,
    }
  }
}
```

However, this implementation gives the error:

`closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows 'z', which is owned by the current function`.

I can use `move` but I'd like to do it by reference. How can I satisfy the compiler?

My current thoughts are to set the function and the closures to the same lifetime, but I wasn't able to find documentation on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can use move but I'd like to do it by reference. How can I satisfy the compiler?

You're doing it by reference in this case. *z* is already a reference, so you would `move` a reference. By leaving out the `move` you're creating a new reference of the type `&'b &'a str` (`&'b` only living inside of your function).

Comment: With `move`, you are not actually moving the reference, but rather _copying_ it, since immutable references are `Copy`. Otherwise it would be illegal to move the reference to two different closures.